# Copy a file but with a "Save as" window

Tags: c#, forms

I just want to copy a file to another location. But with a FileDialog.

I tried the code below but this is not working as I want...

Is there any other solution ?

```
SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
            if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string newDirectory = saveFile.FileName;
                System.IO.File.Copy(Path, newDirectory);
            }
```

EDIT :

I want something like this :

[Word exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Lcq.png)

A Filedialog with the default name of my source file and the right type. You can see an example when you try to save a Word.

Comment: Not working in what sense? It would help if you could explain the current (undesirable) behavior and how it differs from what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `FileStream` class . Which is more flexible, especially if you want to track the data transfer process byte by byte.

```
SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string newDirectory = saveFile.FileName;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
    int currentBlockSize = 0;
    using (source = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
         using (dest = new FileStream(newDirectory, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
         {
              while ((currentBlockSize = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
              {
                  dest.Write(buffer, 0, currentBlockSize);
              }
         } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how do i open a filedialog ?  Look at the screenshot i've made previously if you want.

Comment: I edited the code. Everything is clear in the answer

Comment: Excellent, and now just another question. How can i set the type by default depending of the source file. saveFile.Filter = "??????"

Comment: SaveFileDialog filters : textDialog.Filter = "Text Files | *.txt";  textDialog.DefaultExt = "txt";

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/dd459587(v=vs.95)

Comment: Better link (winforms, not Silverlight): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/savefiledialog-component-windows-forms